# How to close a sheet using a closure method?

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to close a sheet after an API connection finish using a closure method.

So I tried to do that with the code below, but in the case of these codes, they don't work well...

How could I solve this problem?

---

Here are the codes:

TestSheet.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestSheet: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    @State var id:Int = 1
    @State var memo:String = "new Memo"
    @State var isFinish:Bool = false
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                
                Button(action: {
                    appState.makeUpDate(
                        pk:id, memo:memo, finish: {returnData in
                            isFinish = returnData
                        }
                    )
                    if(isFinish){
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                })
                {
                    Text("UPDATE")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppState.swift

```
...
func makeUpDate(pk the_pk:Int, memo the_memo:String, finish:@escaping(Bool)->Void) {
        
        var isFinish:Bool = false
        
        let endpoint: String = "https://sample.com/api/info/\(the_pk)/"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.addValue("token xxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "PUT"
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let newInfo:[String:Any]=["memo":the_memo]
        let jsonInfo: Data
        do {
            jsonInfo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newInfo, options: [])
            urlRequest.httpBody = jsonInfo
        } catch {
            print("Error: cannot create JSON from newInfo")
            return
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling Put")
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("Error: did not response data")
                return
            }
            print("The response code is \(response.statusCode)")
            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            do {
                guard let receivedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData,
                                                                          options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    
                    print("Could not get JSON from responseData as dictionary")
                    return
                }
                print("The request is: " + receivedData.description)
            } catch  {
                print("error parsing response from PUT")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            isFinish = true
            finish(isFinish)
            }
        
        }
        task.resume()
    }
...
```

---

Xcode:Version 12.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isFinish` is updated asynchronously, so we should react on it in different place

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            
            Button(action: {
                appState.makeUpDate(
                    pk:id, memo:memo, finish: {returnData in
                        isFinish = returnData
                    }
                )
            })
            {
                Text("UPDATE")
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isFinish) { result in
            if result {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()    // << here !!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I changed `TestSheet.swift` following your advice and `AppState.swift` as this `DispatchQueue.main.async { isFinish = true finish(isFinish) }` and then the sheet close after API method finish.